# Creating spatially projected polygon grid with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, vector-grid

i need to create a grid with 1x1 square kilometres cells in ArcMap. The operation located in  Data Management Tools -> Feature Class -> Create Net is almost what i need but in the parameters, i can't define a projection the raster grid ist based on. The raster grid must be in the Projection UTM 32N, not in an "undefined" projection.

Is there any operation/function in ArcMap i can use to create a spatially projected polygon grid?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may use the [Grid Index Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000000q000000) tool (**does not have to be used solely for Data Driven Pages*).

> Creates a grid of rectangular polygon features that can be used as an
>   index to specify pages for a map book using Data Driven Pages. A grid
>   can be created that only includes polygon features that intersect
>   another feature layer.

One of the parameters (optional) is input featuers (raster or vector layer) to make the grid off of.  If you use this option your grid layer will be assigned the spatial reference of the input layer.

Answer (score 2):

The result of Create Fishnet is a vector dataset that can have a coordinate system defined by using the Define Projection tool.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of the tool should be an environments button.

[Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Fishnet/00170000002q000000/)

[How it works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Create_Fishnet_works/001700000030000000/)

[Environment Settings](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Output_Coordinate_System/001w00000005000000/)

Inside that dialog expand the output (double arrow).
Either select same as input or as defined below.

But the real answer to the question you don't ask is found in the answer from artwork21 in this thread.  Grid Index Feature Tool creates a vector grid with attributes for row and column. if raster is what you are after