# Exporting a WMS as .TIF fails to grab full extent

Tags: wms, arcgis-pro

Similar question to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187540/clipping-wms-in-region-using-arcgis-for-desktop) post, however, I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.0 and have connected to a WMS.

I've zoomed to the region I wish to export, and when I go to Share > Export > Map, it successfully exports a GeoTIFF, however it looks like a 8.5x11 style rather than the extent of my current map. This is a problem because the region of data that I want  is wider than this extent.

I cannot seem to find a method to change the export extent. I've got to Map > Properties > Extent and attempt to change the settings but the never apply:

- Custom Extent: Current Visible Area
- Check: Clip layers to extent

Map reloads, then I inspect the properties and they have reverted.

How can I export a WMS as a .TIF with the extent of my current zoom?

Comment: You don't export a WMS, you make a GetMap request to fetch a map image (such as GeoTIFF) according to a BBOX.  A WMS is a service it's not exportable.

Comment: @nmtoken Okay well inside ArcGIS Pro, the WMS is displaying in my Map view, so I would've assumed the BBOX would be my visible extent. Is there a way to make a GetMap request and specify the BBOX?