# Creating features(point) grid on polygon

Tags: c#, vector-grid, dotspatial

I am working on GIS based desktop application using C#. I am using dotspatial library in this project.

Now I need to create a grid of features on polygon. This grid cell (rectangle) should be **20*20 Meter Square**.

I have worked on it and able to create grid but facing issue regarding to cell size. Whenever polygon size changed cell size also reduced. My code.

```
         // Polygon Width = 2335
        // Polygon Height = 2054

        int RowsCount = 111;
        int ColumnsCount = 111;

        var maxPointX = Polygon.Extent.MaxPointX;
        var minPointX = Polygon.Extent.MinPointX;

        var maxPointY = Polygon.Extent.MaxPointY;
        var minPointY = Polygon.Extent.MinPointY;

        var dXStep = (maxPointX - minPointX) / (ColumnsCount - 1);
        var dYStep = (maxPointY - minPointY) / (RowsCount - 1);

        var gridColumnsPoints = new double[1000000];
        var gridRowPoints = new double[1000000];

        //   Calculate the coordinates of grid
        var nextPointX = minPointX;

        for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnsCount; i++)
        {
            gridColumnsPoints[i - 1] = nextPointX;
            nextPointX = nextPointX + dXStep;
        }

        var nextPointY = minPointY;

        for (int i = 1; i <= RowsCount; i++)
        {
            gridRowPoints[i - 1] = nextPointY;
            nextPointY = nextPointY + dYStep;
        }
```

Output
[image]

Now when I tried this code on small size of Polygon then grid cell size also decreased.

[image]

I know my approach is not correct, So I have searched on it and got some tools. like

[Creating spatially projected polygon grid with ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79681/creating-spatially-projected-polygon-grid-with-arcmap)

But I want to create it in C# and unable to found any algorithm or any other helping material.